# How to call a ViewController method from AppDelegate after Launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

My ViewController instance is connected to my AppDelegate like this:

*AppDelegate.h*

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ViewController *myVC;
```

synthesized in *AppDelegate.m*

*ViewController.m*

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.myVC = self;
}
```

In the AppDelegate I am using the method:

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)
url sourceApplication:(NSString *) sourceApplication annotation:(id)
annotation
```

while processing the URL further I have to call a method of the current instance of my ViewController like:

```
[myVC showResultsOfProcessedURL:url];
```

This works fine when the App is running but it won't be called when the App is being freshly launched (not just became active again).
I see that the AppDelegate can't know about the ViewController instance yet. But I don't know how to make him know.

Comment: Why not to do herever you are doing in showResultsOfProcessedURL you should do it in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: That's not a standard way to wire up the relationship between an app delegate and a view controller. It's pretty cyclical and pretty much doomed. Read about delegation, or protocols and re think how you are approaching this. Can you explain why your VC is defined as an IBOutlet?

Comment: Most of the time you want your VC to know about your AppDelegate, not the other way around. Have your VC call the method when it's ready, instead of calling it directly in AppDelegate

Comment: Ok I was able to rebuild my ViewController method to work in my AppDelegate. Thank you though :)